# How do you make a Java checkbox open a window?

Tags: java, window

I made a Checkbox so where when you click it it opens another window with more checkboxes. How is it you would go about making those checkboxes open another window?

Comment: Use Event Handling whenever Checkbox is selected........ Open a new Window...... It's depends on you which Window u want to open means u can open dependent like JOptionPane or independent like JFrame from this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an actionlistener to your checkBox component?

It's hard to see what excactly you're trying to achieve; but from what you write it shouldn't be more than that.

You can try this tutorial, for starters:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JCheckBoxaddActionListenerActionListenerlis.htm